# Comparing two dataframes and only showing the unmatched column records

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I have a list of dictionaries converted to Pandas Dataframe
I am able to print the unmatched record but I don't want the whole record but only the mismatched column of the record.

`{'A':5,'B':6,'C': 7}]` list 2 is: `[{'A':5,'B':8,'C': 7}]`,. I want to get only output of B where the mismatch is. Assuming list of dictionaries will have multiple dictionaries. I have two dataframes and am comparing to find the non matched records.

I need to get an idea on how to do that

Possible solutions tried:-

Finding the common records and dropping from dataframe but I am getting entire rows.

However I only need columns only that have unmatched values.

Please note there are around 50 columns

### for df1

```py
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
0  2013-11-24  Banana  22.1  Yellow
1  2013-11-24  Orange   8.6  Orange
2  2013-11-24   Apple   7.6   Green
3  2013-11-24  Celery  10.2   Green
```

### for df2

```py
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
0  2013-11-24  Banana  22.1  Orange
1  2013-11-24  Orange   8.6  Orange
2  2013-11-24   Apple   7.6   Green
3  2013-11-24  Celery  10.2   Green
```

### for df_diff

```py
Color
1 Orange
```

Comment: Please show samples of your dataframes and your expected output ;)

Comment: [{'A':5,'B':6,'C': 7}]  list 2 is:     [{'A':5,'B':8,'C': 7}] ,.                     I want to get only output of B where the mismatch is. Assuming list of dictionaries will have multiple dictionaries. I have two dataframes and am comparing to find the non matched records.

Comment: how would each list look if it's longer? Would each dict in each list have the same keys?

Comment: yeah, you're going to need to be clearer.  What would the dataframe look like?

Comment: Each dict have the same keys in the list
If there are 100 keys they will be same in both list

Comment: Thanks .I am able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, given the following dictionaries:

```py
dict_1 = {
    "Date": {0: "2013-11-24", 1: "2013-11-24", 2: "2013-11-24", 3: "2013-11-24"},
    "Fruit": {0: "Banana", 1: "Orange", 2: "Apple", 3: "Celery"},
    "Num": {0: 22.1, 1: 8.6, 2: 7.6, 3: 10.2},
    "Color": {0: "Yellow", 1: "Orange", 2: "Green", 3: "Green"},
}

dict_2 = {
    "Date": {0: "2013-11-03", 1: "2013-11-24", 2: "2013-11-24", 3: "2013-11-24"},
    "Fruit": {0: "Banana", 1: "Orange", 2: "Citrus", 3: "Celery"},
    "Num": {0: 22.1, 1: 2.2, 2: 7.6, 3: 0.2},
    "Color": {0: "Orange", 1: "Orange", 2: "Green", 3: "Green"},
}
```

You could find the differences like this:

```py
diff_dict = {}
for outer_key, inner_dict in dict_1.items():
    diff_dict[outer_key] = {}
    for inner_key, inner_value in inner_dict.items():
        if (other_value := dict_2[outer_key][inner_key]) != inner_value:
            diff_dict[outer_key][inner_key] = other_value
        else:
            diff_dict[outer_key][inner_key] = "-"
```

And then visualize them with Pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

print(pd.DataFrame(diff_dict))
# Output

         Date   Fruit  Num   Color
0  2013-11-03       -    -  Orange
1           -       -  2.2       -
2           -  Citrus    -       -
3           -       -  0.2       -
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Fruit":['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery'],
                  'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2], 'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Fruit":['Banana','Orange','Mango','Celery'],
                  'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,15], 'Color':['Orage','Orange','Green','Green']})
```

You can get the mismatches with a boolean indexing

```py
df_diff = df1[df1!=df2].fillna('')
```

If you want both columns where there is a mistmatch and the mismatched value

```py
{col:i for col in df_diff.columns for i in df_diff[col] if len(str(i)) > 0}
```

If you only want the column where there is a mismatch

```py
[col for col in df_diff.columns for i in df_diff[col] if len(str(i))>0]
```